# Getting newest message from user

Tags: php, sql

How can I get the newest message from the person who sends a user a message?

Right now it's showing...

```
first_name last_name       This is the newest message I sent you   2012-08-11 14:23:38

first_name last_name       test                                    2012-08-11 14:20:35

<?php 
    echo '<div id ="inbox_name">Name</div><div id="inbox_message">Message</div><div id="inbox_time">Time</div><div id="inbox_line"></div>';
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `private_messages` WHERE `to_id`=$session_user_id ORDER BY `time_sent` DESC") or die("Error connecting to database. Please try again later.");
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $to_id = $row['to_id'];
        $from_id = $row['from_id'];
        $message = $row['message'];
        $time= $row['time_sent'];

        $message_information = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sentrl_users` WHERE `id`=$from_id LIMIT 1");
        while ($row_information = mysql_fetch_array($message_information)) {
            $first_name = $row_information['first_name'];
            $last_name = $row_information['last_name'];
            $username = $row_information['username'];
            echo '<div id="inbox_information"><div id="recieved_name">'. $first_name . ' ' . $last_name .'</div><div id="recieved_message">'. $message .'</div><div id="recieved_time">'. $time .'</div></div>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

I tried using limit 1, but that didnt work.  I'm trying to just get the newest message WITHOUT duplicating the `first_name` and `last_name`.

Comment: Have you tried adding "LIMIT 1" to your first query? It seems the first while loop is run twice because the SELECT returns two rows.

Comment: yeah i did...when i do, the entire thing only returns one result which is not what i want. What i want is returning one result for one user...

Comment: How many users and messages does your current database contain? What is the expected output of the final (working) version of the code?

Comment: like how facebook does it...they only show the recent message sent by the user....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is ONLY ONE row, instead of

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
//EVERYTHING INSIDE THE ORIGINAL WHILE LOOP
}
```

you should write

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$array[$row["from_id"]]=$row;
} 
foreach($array as $row){
//EVERYTHING INSIDE THE ORIGINAL WHILE LOOP
}
```

Comment: That only shows 1 result which im not looking for...im looking to show the recent message sent by a user to this user...like how facebook does it

Comment: i don't understand... you want to show the last message sent to you by each user?

Comment: yes. My code up there shows each message that is sent so for example John sends me three messages 1) hi 2) there 3) new message...my code right now displays all three messages when i only want it to show the recent message which is message 3...new message...

Comment: ok i get it now. I'd write:
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$array[$row["from_id"]]=$row;
}
foreach($array as $row){
//EVERYTHING INSIDE THE ORIGINAL WHILE LOOP
}